# Get all resources in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

In the **[AppName].g.resources** file, how do I enumerate through all the resources inside?

For example, there is:
`readme.txt

images/logo.png

images/img.jpg`

...etc

I know how to read them individually, but what if I want to get all resources from the "folder" **images**?

**UPDATE**: Oops my bad ^^ Duplicate of [Enumerating .NET assembly resources at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517407/enumerating-net-assembly-resources-at-runtime)

Comment: try exploring Application.Current.Resources

Comment: I did but no luck :( It doesn't return items compiled under "Resources" in VS2010

Comment: Don't confuse Application.Current.Resources with the resources located in your assembly. The first is for ResourceDictionaries and WPF object. The second is for files/images/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try the GetResourceStream method present in Assembly class to get the stream to resource file.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

I dont think you can enumerate like how you do for folders.

Another way is get resource names
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames.aspx