# Find all embedded resources in another assembly

Tags: c#, resources, embedded-resource

I'm working on localization for my project. For this, I have a class which should load an embedded resource from another assembly, and then read out the strings.

But also I need to know which resource files this assembly contains.
The number and which languages those are, is unknown.

So how do I find out how the ".resx" file in this assembly is named?
Those all have the same scheme: "de-DE.resx", "en-US.resx", and so on.

I need to know how many of those files are contained in this assembly,
and which languages they are.

I know that the ResourceManager has access to them, thus it should be possible to access this information programatically too...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should use `GetManifestResourceNames` method from `Assembly` class ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames(v=vs.100).aspx)):

```
string[] resourceNames = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
foreach(string resourceName in resourceNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(resourceName);
}
```