# how to use GetResourceData

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, bitmap, embedded-resource

I created a resources file with PNG files using this command:

```
resgen.exe Test3.resx Test3.resources
```

I can iterate through the resources and I can succesfully see they are included,
I can also see that the datatype of each element is System.Drawing.Bitmap,
however I am unable to convert the byte array back to Bitmap,

either PNG need a different retrieval and conversion or I'm just going crazy

does someone know what am i missing?

```
   Public Function GetImageResources() As Dictionary(Of String, Bitmap)

    Dim resourceReader As New ResourceReader(".\Test3.resources")
    Dim resourcesEnumerator As IDictionaryEnumerator = resourceReader.GetEnumerator()
    Dim resourcesFound As New Dictionary(Of String, Bitmap)

    Do While resourcesEnumerator.MoveNext()

        Dim dataType As String = Nothing
        Dim data() As Byte = Nothing
        resourceReader.GetResourceData(resourcesEnumerator.Key, dataType, data)

        Dim finalImage As New Bitmap(New MemoryStream(data))
        'RUNTIME ERROR: Parameter is not valid
        'dataType value = System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, ...

        resourcesFound.Add(resourcesEnumerator.Key.ToString(), finalImage)

    Loop
    resourceReader.Close()


    Return resourcesFound
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem. I had hard time with reading resource stream due to an offset of 4 that is always there for DataType: ResourceTypeCode.Stream. You can see that offset in [Microsoft code in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcereader(v=vs.110).aspx) (The code is very nice for Bitmap).

I've done a little project about resource reading and uri at [GitHub](https://github.com/EricOuellet2/UriInternal)

For an image (In folder "[YourProject]/Icons/About.png") with build action defined as "Resource":

```
        System.IO.Stream stream = HQ.Util.General.ResourceHelper.LoadResourceFromUri(
            HQ.Util.General.ResourceHelper.GetLocationUri("Icons/About.png"));

        Image image = new Bitmap(stream);
```

This is my ResourceHelper file (if it can help you) ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Resources;

namespace HQ.Util.General
{
    public static class ResourceHelper
    {
        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// The resource should be defined as 'Resource' not as 'Embedded resource'.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="resourcePath">The resource path</param>
        /// <param name="assembly">If null, then use calling assembly to find the resource</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Uri GetLocationUri(string resourcePath, Assembly assembly = null)
        {
            if (assembly == null)
            {
                assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
            }

            resourcePath = resourcePath.Replace('\\', '/');

            return new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/" + assembly.GetName().Name + ";component" +
                (resourcePath[0] == '/' ? resourcePath : "/" + resourcePath), UriKind.Absolute);
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// Will load resource from any assembly that is part of the application.
        /// It does not rely on Application which is specific to a (UI) frameowrk.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="uri"></param>
        /// <param name="asm"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Stream LoadResourceFromUri(Uri uri, Assembly asm = null)
        {
            Stream stream = null;

            if (uri.Authority.StartsWith("application") && uri.Scheme == "pack")
            {
                string localPath = uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Path, UriFormat.UriEscaped);

                int indexLocalPathWithoutAssembly = localPath.IndexOf(";component/");
                if (indexLocalPathWithoutAssembly == -1)
                {
                    indexLocalPathWithoutAssembly = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    indexLocalPathWithoutAssembly += 11;
                }

                if (asm != null) // Take the provided assembly, do not check for the asm in the uri.
                {
                    stream = GetAssemblyResourceStream(asm, localPath.Substring(indexLocalPathWithoutAssembly));
                }
                else
                {
                    if (uri.Segments.Length > 1)
                    {
                        if (uri.Segments[0] == "/" && uri.Segments[1].EndsWith(";component/"))
                        {
                            int index = uri.Segments[1].IndexOf(";");
                            if (index > 0)
                            {
                                string assemblyName = uri.Segments[1].Substring(0, index);

                                foreach (Assembly asmIter in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
                                {
                                    if (asmIter.GetName().Name == assemblyName)
                                    {
                                        stream = GetAssemblyResourceStream(asmIter, localPath.Substring(indexLocalPathWithoutAssembly));
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (stream == null)
                    {
                        asm = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
                        stream = GetAssemblyResourceStream(asm, localPath.Substring(indexLocalPathWithoutAssembly));
                    }
                }
            }
            return stream;
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// The path separator is '/'.  The path should not start with '/'.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="asm"></param>
        /// <param name="path"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Stream GetAssemblyResourceStream(Assembly asm, string path)
        {
            // Just to be sure
            if (path[0] == '/')
            {
                path = path.Substring(1);
            }

            // Just to be sure
            if (path.IndexOf('\\') == -1)
            {
                path = path.Replace('\\', '/');
            }

            Stream resStream = null;

            string resName = asm.GetName().Name + ".g.resources"; // Ref: Thomas Levesque Answer at:
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517407/enumerating-net-assembly-resources-at-runtime

            using (var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resName))
            {
                using (var resReader = new System.Resources.ResourceReader(stream))
                {
                    string dataType = null;
                    byte[] data = null;
                    try
                    {
                        resReader.GetResourceData(path.ToLower(), out dataType, out data);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        DebugPrintResources(resReader);
                    }

                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        switch (dataType) // COde from 
                        {
                            // Handle internally serialized string data (ResourceTypeCode members).
                            case "ResourceTypeCode.String":
                                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(data));
                                string binData = reader.ReadString();
                                Console.WriteLine("   Recreated Value: {0}", binData);
                                break;
                            case "ResourceTypeCode.Int32":
                                Console.WriteLine("   Recreated Value: {0}", BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0));
                                break;
                            case "ResourceTypeCode.Boolean":
                                Console.WriteLine("   Recreated Value: {0}", BitConverter.ToBoolean(data, 0));
                                break;
                            // .jpeg image stored as a stream.
                            case "ResourceTypeCode.Stream":
                                ////const int OFFSET = 4;
                                ////int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
                                ////Bitmap value1 = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(data, OFFSET, size));
                                ////Console.WriteLine("   Recreated Value: {0}", value1);

                                const int OFFSET = 4;
                                resStream = new MemoryStream(data, OFFSET, data.Length - OFFSET);

                                break;
                            // Our only other type is DateTimeTZI.
                            default:
                                ////// No point in deserializing data if the type is unavailable.
                                ////if (dataType.Contains("DateTimeTZI") && loaded)
                                ////{
                                ////    BinaryFormatter binFmt = new BinaryFormatter();
                                ////    object value2 = binFmt.Deserialize(new MemoryStream(data));
                                ////    Console.WriteLine("   Recreated Value: {0}", value2);
                                ////}
                                ////break;
                                break;
                        }

                        // resStream = new MemoryStream(resData);
                    }
                }
            }

            return resStream;
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        private static void DebugPrintResources(System.Resources.ResourceReader reader)
        {
            Debug.Print("Begin dump resources: ---------------------");
            foreach (DictionaryEntry item in reader)
            {
                Debug.Print(item.Key.ToString());
            }
            Debug.Print("End   dump resources: ---------------------");
        }

        // ******************************************************************        // ******************************************************************
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure yet how to use GetResourceData, but I at least this code does the same desired effect:

```
Public Function GetImageResources() As Dictionary(Of String, Bitmap)

    Dim resourcesFound As New Dictionary(Of String, Bitmap)

    Dim resourceReader As New ResourceReader(".\Test3.resources")
    Dim resourcesEnumerator As IDictionaryEnumerator = resourceReader.GetEnumerator()
    Dim resourceSet As New ResourceSet(".\Test3.resources")

    Do While resourcesEnumerator.MoveNext()

        Dim retrievedObject As Object = resourceSet.GetObject(resourcesEnumerator.Key.ToString())

        Dim convertedBitmap As Bitmap = DirectCast(retrievedObject, Bitmap)
        resourcesFound.Add(resourcesEnumerator.Key.ToString(), convertedBitmap)

    Loop
    resourceReader.Close()
    resourceSet.Close()

    Return resourcesFound
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the exact same problem.  What I discovered is four bytes are added to the front of the byte array when saved to a resource file.  I have no idea why nor I have found any documentation of it.  Regardless, the following will serve to correctly convert your image data back:

```
public Image FixImageDataFromResourceFile(byte[] byteArrayFromResourceFile)
{
    byte[] fixedImageData = new byte[byteArrayFromResourceFile.Length - 4];
    Array.Copy(byteArrayFromResourceFile, 4, fixedImageData, 0, fixedImageData.Length);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fixedImageData);
    Image retval = Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
    ms.Close();
    return retval;
}
```

If anyone knows what the four bytes are for or can find documentation regarding it, I would love to be informed of it.  My only guess is the four bytes are used to identify the data type in the resource file but certainly renders just about any information useless without proper notice.